# Why is an explicit construction considered an (implicit) narrowing conversion?

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, clang++, narrowing

Consider the following code:

```
uint32_t foo(uint64_t x ) {
    auto y = uint32_t { x };
    return y;
}
```

It is considered a narrowing conversion the compiler feels compelled to warn me about (GCC 9) or even declare an error (clang 9): [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/eG2MmA).

My questions:

1. Why is `uint32_t { x }` less explicit than `static_cast<uint32_t>(x)`?
2. Why is this more severe with clang than with GCC, meriting an error?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is `uint32_t { x }` less explicit than `static_cast<uint32_t>(x)`?

It's not less explicit, it's just not allowed.  Narrowing conversions are not allowed when doing direct or copy list initialization.  When you do `auto y = uint32_t { x };` you are direct-list-initializing `y` with a narrowing conversion. (Guaranteed Copy elision means there is no temporary here anymore)

> Why is this more severe with clang than with GCC, meriting an error?

It's up the the implementers.  Apparently clang wants to be more strict and issue a hard error, but both are fine. The standard only requires a diagnostic message be given, and a warning or error covers that.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @NathanOliver's answer - the warnings and errors go away if we construct the 32-bit integer like so:

```
uint32_t foo(uint64_t x ) {
    auto y = uint32_t(x);
    return y;
}
```

So, `(x)` and `{x}` here are **not semantically equivalent** (even if the same constructor would end up getting called, had it been a class). The no-narrowing guarantee in the standard apparently only applies to list-initialization, IIANM.

So, take this is a motivation for using curly-bracket initialization, if you want to be extra careful (or parentheses if you want to not be bothered.)

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization:

> **Narrowing conversions**
>
> list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by
>   prohibiting the following:
>
> ...
>
> -conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type that cannot represent all values of the original, except where source
>   is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in the
>   target type

This sounds like clang is more conformant than gcc here (though beware that I'm not a language lawyer)*: the standard mandates that, if you use initalizer lists, you aren't in any danger of a narrowing conversion. This is a conscious design choice to remedy the rather promiscuous implicit conversion built into the language - and the admittedly clear way that you spell it out in your example is a collateral annoyance.

Edit: * and it didn't take long - it seems "not allowed" at cppreference translates to "implementer dependent" in the standard, as per NathanOliver's answer. That's what I get for not checking the source.